# How to properly set up Ember auto-imports using VSCode and the Javascript Language Service?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up auto-imports in VSCode for my Ember project and I'm encountering issues with imports from the Ember library.

I have properly set up imports from within my application, those work just fine, but when trying to import from `@ember`, it either doesn't find the import at all, or it's imported from a ridiculous relative path, or it's imported just fine, in some cases.

My `jsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2018",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "sbct-web/tests/*": ["./tests/*"],
            "sbct-web/config/*": ["./config/*"],
            "sbct-web/*": ["./app/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "tmp",
        "vendor",
        ".git",
        "dist",
        "temp",
        "public",
    ]
}
```

I also tried with a dumbed down version that only had the `exclude` field, but the results were the same. I also tried to force `typeAcquisitions`, same results (I suspect the types are fetched just fine, because I can peek definitions of @ember modules).

In order to better understand the issue, here's a short recording of what I'm encountering:

[image: ember auto imports]

Answer (score 1):

The VSCode IntelliSense for javascript works from the type definitions in your package.json

I've found that be specifically adding the @types/ember package. VSCode is able to properly auto-import.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/ember
```